# change width SysIPAddress32

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm trying implement IP edit. This my code:

```pascal
unit Main;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.CommCtrl,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type

  TIpEdit = class(TWinControl)
  strict protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
    procedure WMSetFont(var Message: TWMSetFont); message WM_SETFONT;      
  end;

  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Btn1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FIpEdit: TIpEdit;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TIPEdit }

procedure TIPEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  InitCommonControl(ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES);
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  CreateSubClass(Params, WC_IPADDRESS);
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_TABSTOP or WS_CHILD;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  inherited;
  Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTARROWS;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.WMSetFont(var Message: TWMSetFont);
var
  LF: LOGFONT;
begin
  if GetObject(Message.Font, SizeOf(LF), @LF) <> 0 then
  begin
    Message.Font := CreateFontIndirect(LF);
    inherited;
  end;
end;

{ TMainForm }

procedure TMainForm.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FIpEdit.Width := FIpEdit.Width + 100;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FIpEdit := TIpEdit.Create(Self);
  FIpEdit.Parent := Self;
  FIpEdit.SetBounds(10, 10, 120, 21);
end;

end.
```

Before Btn1.Click

[image]

After Btn1.Click

[image]

As a result: Control change own width but not change width internal edits.

I try fix by two ways

- Use *RecreateWnd*. This works, but IMHO its ugly solution.
- Fix internal edits width manualy. This works, but it is difficult to
  implement, due to the internal work of the control

Maybe I missed something and there is a simpler solution?

**Edit:**

I tested the *RecreateWnd*, but it can not be used when using DevExpress layout control. It seems that layout control uses the direct call of the API bypassing the SetBounds method. In this case *RecreateWnd* can not be using.

The final conclusion is:

- *RecreateWnd* is simple solution with some ristrictions
- RepeatUntil [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630887/3907965) more difficult, but always working

Comment: A lot of things in the VCL use `RecreateWnd` to apply window changes. It may not be an optimal solution at times, but it is hardly an ugly solution, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TPanel` with child `TEdit` controls to create your own IP Edit, That will give you more control of their property.

This how its look at run time:
[image]

I wrote this time ago, its not completed work but may give an idea of what i mean.

```
unit IPEdit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Graphics, System.UITypes;

type
  TExitType = (etNone, etNext);

type
  TIPEdit = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    FPart1      : TEdit;
    FPart2      : TEdit;
    FPart3      : TEdit;
    FPart4      : TEdit;
    FSplitter1  : TPanel;
    FSplitter2  : TPanel;
    FSplitter3  : TPanel;
    FRiseErr    : Boolean;
    FErrMsg     : string;
    FExitType   : TExitType;
    FBevelInner : TPanelBevel;
    FLeadingzero: Boolean;
    procedure SetExitType(Value : TExitType);
    procedure SetBevelInner(Value: TPanelBevel);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  protected
    procedure EditOnKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure EditOnChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditOnExit(Sender: TObject);
  published
    property ShowError: Boolean read FRiseErr write FRiseErr default False;
    property Leadingzero: Boolean read FLeadingzero write FLeadingzero default False;
    property ErrorText: string read FErrMsg write FErrMsg;
    property ExitType: TExitType read FExitType write SetExitType default etNext;
    property BevelInner: TPanelBevel read FBevelInner write SetBevelInner default bvNone;
  end;


implementation

const
  Msg_Err_Value_Exceeded  = 'Value cannot be greater than 255';
  SplitterWidth  = 5;

{ TIPEdit }

constructor TIPEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  if AOwner is TWinControl then
    Parent           := TWinControl(AOwner);
  { Main Panle Style }
  ParentBackground := False;
  BevelKind        := bkFlat;
  BevelOuter       := bvNone;
  Color            := clWindow;
  Height           := 25;
  Width            := 165;
  Caption          := '';
  /////////////////////////////

  { Set Handlers}
  OnResize := OnPanelResize;

  { Create child controls }
  FPart1            := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FPart1.Name       := 'IPEditPart1';
  FPart1.Visible    := False;
  FSplitter1        := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FSplitter1.Name   := 'IPSplitter1';
  FSplitter1.Visible:= False;
  FPart2            := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FPart2.Name       := 'IPEditPart2';
  FPart2.Visible    := False;
  FSplitter2        := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FSplitter2.Name   := 'IPSplitter2';
  FSplitter2.Visible:= False;
  FPart3            := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FPart3.Name       := 'IPEditPart3';
  FPart3.Visible    := False;
  FSplitter3        := TPanel.Create(Self);
  FSplitter3.Name   := 'IPSplitter3';
  FSplitter3.Visible:= False;
  FPart4            := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FPart4.Name       := 'IPEditPart4';
  FPart4.Visible    := False;
  FPart1.Align      := alLeft;
  FSplitter1.Align  := alLeft;
  FPart2.Align      := alLeft;
  FSplitter2.Align  := alLeft;
  FPart3.Align      := alLeft;
  FSplitter3.Align  := alLeft;
  FPart4.Align      := alLeft;
  /////////////////////////////

  { Set Child Style }
  // This order is very important //
  FPart1.Parent           := TWinControl(Self);
  FSplitter1.Parent       := TWinControl(Self);
  FPart2.Parent           := TWinControl(Self);
  FSplitter2.Parent       := TWinControl(Self);
  FPart3.Parent           := TWinControl(Self);
  FSplitter3.Parent       := TWinControl(Self);
  FPart4.Parent           := TWinControl(Self);
  FPart1.Visible          := True;
  FSplitter1.Visible      := True;
  FPart2.Visible          := True;
  FSplitter2.Visible      := True;
  FPart3.Visible          := True;
  FSplitter3.Visible      := True;
  FPart4.Visible          := True;
  //////////////////////////////////


  FPart1.Alignment             := taCenter;
  FPart2.Alignment             := taCenter;
  FPart3.Alignment             := taCenter;
  FPart4.Alignment             := taCenter;



  FPart1.Margins.Left          := 0;
  FPart2.Margins.Left          := 0;
  FPart3.Margins.Left          := 0;
  FPart4.Margins.Left          := 0;
  FSplitter1.Margins.Left      := 0;
  FSplitter2.Margins.Left      := 0;
  FSplitter3.Margins.Left      := 0;
  FPart1.Margins.Right         := 0;
  FPart2.Margins.Right         := 0;
  FPart3.Margins.Right         := 0;
  FPart4.Margins.Right         := 0;
  FSplitter1.Margins.Right     := 0;
  FSplitter2.Margins.Right     := 0;
  FSplitter3.Margins.Right     := 0;


  FPart1.AlignWithMargins      := True;
  FSplitter1.AlignWithMargins  := True;
  FPart2.AlignWithMargins      := True;
  FSplitter2.AlignWithMargins  := True;
  FPart3.AlignWithMargins      := True;
  FSplitter3.AlignWithMargins  := True;
  FPart4.AlignWithMargins      := True;
  FPart1.AutoSize              := False;
  FPart2.AutoSize              := False;
  FPart3.AutoSize              := False;
  FPart4.AutoSize              := False;
  FPart1.BorderStyle           := bsNone;
  FPart2.BorderStyle           := bsNone;
  FPart3.BorderStyle           := bsNone;
  FPart4.BorderStyle           := bsNone;
  FPart1.NumbersOnly           := True;
  FPart2.NumbersOnly           := True;
  FPart3.NumbersOnly           := True;
  FPart4.NumbersOnly           := True;
  FPart1.MaxLength             := 3;
  FPart2.MaxLength             := 3;
  FPart3.MaxLength             := 3;
  FPart4.MaxLength             := 3;
  FPart1.Width                 := 36;
  FPart2.Width                 := 36;
  FPart3.Width                 := 36;
  FPart4.Width                 := 36;
  FSplitter1.Alignment         := taCenter;
  FSplitter2.Alignment         := taCenter;
  FSplitter3.Alignment         := taCenter;
  FSplitter1.Caption           := '.';
  FSplitter2.Caption           := '.';
  FSplitter3.Caption           := '.';
  FSplitter1.BevelOuter        := bvNone;
  FSplitter2.BevelOuter        := bvNone;
  FSplitter3.BevelOuter        := bvNone;
  FSplitter1.Color             := clWindow;
  FSplitter2.Color             := clWindow;
  FSplitter3.Color             := clWindow;
  FSplitter1.ParentBackground  := False;
  FSplitter2.ParentBackground  := False;
  FSplitter3.ParentBackground  := False;
  FSplitter1.TabStop           := False;
  FSplitter2.TabStop           := False;
  FSplitter3.TabStop           := False;
  FSplitter1.Width             := SplitterWidth;
  FSplitter2.Width             := SplitterWidth;
  FSplitter3.Width             := SplitterWidth;
  FSplitter1.Font.Style        := FSplitter1.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  FSplitter2.Font.Style        := FSplitter2.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  FSplitter3.Font.Style        := FSplitter3.Font.Style + [fsBold];
  //////////////////////////////

  {Set Child handlers}
  FPart1.OnChange  := EditOnChange;
  FPart2.OnChange  := EditOnChange;
  FPart3.OnChange  := EditOnChange;
  FPart4.OnChange  := EditOnChange;
  FPart1.OnKeyDown := EditOnKeyDown;
  FPart2.OnKeyDown := EditOnKeyDown;
  FPart3.OnKeyDown := EditOnKeyDown;
  FPart4.OnKeyDown := EditOnKeyDown;
  FPart1.OnExit    := EditOnExit;
  FPart2.OnExit    := EditOnExit;
  FPart3.OnExit    := EditOnExit;
  FPart4.OnExit    := EditOnExit;

  {Set Child control tab order for the handlers work}
  FPart1.TabOrder := 0;
  FPart2.TabOrder := 1;
  FPart3.TabOrder := 2;
  FPart4.TabOrder := 3;

  FPart1.Text := '1';
  FPart2.Text := '2';
  FPart3.Text := '3';
  FPart4.Text := '4';

  FExitType := etNext;
  FErrMsg   := Msg_Err_Value_Exceeded;
end;

destructor TIPEdit.Destroy;
begin
  FPart1.Free;
  FPart2.Free;
  FPart3.Free;
  FPart4.Free;

  FSplitter1.Free;
  FSplitter2.Free;
  FSplitter3.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.EditOnChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  iValue     : Integer;
  bValGrater : Boolean;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if NOT (Sender is TEdit) then Exit;
  bValGrater := False;
  if TryStrToInt(TEdit(Sender).Text, iValue) then begin
    if (iValue > 255) then begin
      iValue     := 255;
      bValGrater := True;
      TEdit(Sender).Text := iValue.ToString;
      if (FRiseErr and bValGrater) then
        raise Exception.Create(FErrMsg);
    end;
  end;
  if Length(TEdit(Sender).Text) = 3 then begin
    case FExitType of
      etNone: ;
      etNext: FindNextControl(TEdit(Sender), True, False, False).SetFocus;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.EditOnKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
const
    vkReturn  = $0D;
begin
  if not (Sender is TEdit) then Exit;
  if Key = vkReturn then
    FindNextControl(TEdit(Sender), True, False, False).SetFocus;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.OnPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
const
  EditCount      = 4;
  SplitterCount  = 3;
var
  EditWidth      : Integer;
  FSplitterWidth : Integer;
  EditMargin     : Integer;
begin
  EditWidth := Trunc(((Width) / EditCount) - (SplitterCount * (SplitterWidth)));
  FPart1.Width := EditWidth;
  FPart2.Width := EditWidth;
  FPart3.Width := EditWidth;
  FPart4.Width := EditWidth;
  FSplitterWidth := Trunc(( (Width) - ( EditWidth * EditCount) ) / SplitterCount);
  FSplitter1.Width := FSplitterWidth;
  FSplitter2.Width := FSplitterWidth;
  FSplitter3.Width := FSplitterWidth;

  {Center edits text vertically == this is a temporary workaround}
  FPart1.Margins.Top := 0;
  FPart2.Margins.Top := 0;
  FPart3.Margins.Top := 0;
  FPart4.Margins.Top := 0;
  EditMargin := Round( ((Height / 5)));
  FPart1.Margins.Top    := EditMargin;
  FPart2.Margins.Top    := EditMargin;
  FPart3.Margins.Top    := EditMargin;
  FPart4.Margins.Top    := EditMargin;
  FSplitter1.Margins.Top     := EditMargin + SplitterWidth; { the +lblWidth to make it lower than the edits}
  FSplitter2.Margins.Top     := EditMargin + SplitterWidth;
  FSplitter3.Margins.Top     := EditMargin + SplitterWidth;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.SetBevelInner(Value: TPanelBevel);
begin
  TPanel(Self).BevelInner := Value;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.SetExitType(Value: TExitType);
begin
  FExitType := Value;
end;

procedure TIPEdit.EditOnExit(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if not (Sender IS TEdit) then Exit;
  if FLeadingzero then begin
    if Length(TEdit(Sender).Text) >= 1 then
    for I := Length(TEdit(Sender).Text) to 2 do begin
      TEdit(Sender).Text := '0' + TEdit(Sender).Text;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

The control does not provide a mechanism to update its layout after it has been created. Yes you could hack at the internal edit controls, but that is dangerous. You'd be relying on undocumented implementation detail that is subject to change.

In summary, I would say that recreating the window is the best solution available.